# C pointer sum "not working"

Tags: c, pointers, printf

I do not understand what is the point in the else sentence `*nombre=(*nombre)++`.

Output shows `"fernando"` and what i thought it was going to show was `"ffsoboep"` because of the sum. But it seems that `*nombre=(*nombre)+1` is different to *`nombre=(*nombre)++;`

My question is why is that happening? how does "++" operator works in that case. Thanks.

```
void recursiva (char * nombre)
{

    if (*nombre != '\0')
    {
        recursiva(nombre+1);
        if(*nombre > 'A' && *nombre < 'Z')
        {
             *nombre=*nombre | 32;
        }
        else
        {
             *nombre=(*nombre)++;
             printf("%c \n",*nombre);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    char nombre[]="Fernando";
    recursiva(nombre);
    printf("%s",nombre);
}
```

Comment: Why did you write `*nombre=(*nombre)++;`? Writing that is just asking for pain.

Comment: It sounds like you just want `(*nombre)++`.

Comment: @rullof: `(*nombre)++` works fine when I try it.

Comment: I also cannot understand that Abba song myself 'fernando'.

Comment: check sequence point. `*nombre=(*nombre)++;` is UB.

Comment: I ran the program and got "ffsoboep".

Answer (score 2):

```
(*nombre)++
```

doesn't mean the same thing as

```
*nombre + 1
```

It means "return the original value of `*nombre`, with the side effect of increasing `*nombre`'s value by 1". Note that when exactly the value of `*nombre` increases is rather vague; while it happens after the value of `(*nombre)++` is computed, it might happen before, after, or during the assignment to `*nombre`, with unpredictable results.

If you want to increase the value of `*nombre`, you don't need to assign the value of `(*nombre)++` back to `*nombre`, and in fact, trying to do so is [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). As a first approximation, the program is allowed to do anything, up to and including [making demons fly out your nose](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html). Just use `++`:

```
(*nombre)++;
```

or `+= 1`:

```
*nombre += 1;
```

Comment: Yeah, i know, its not my code its form a final exam of my collage...so, i'm just trying to understand what it does, in XCODE IDE it does anything...but in codeblocks shows every letter + 1. so...dont really know what to answer.

Comment: I'm pretty sure postfix `++` *is* defined to increment *and then* return the original.  That's why we have the prefix `++`.

Comment: @SebastianC: Expanded answer a bit.

Comment: @sqykly: You'd think so, but nope! No such sequencing relationship is defined.

Comment: Which sequence are you talking about, exactly?  I'm saying that the value of the expression `foo++` is defined to be the same as the value of `foo` (had it never been incremented at all).  Of this I am quite certain.  If you're talking about the case of `bar = foo++` being implemented as `{int temp = foo ; ++foo ; bar = temp}` vs `bar = foo; ++foo`, it's impossible to have a different outcome unless you overload `++` or `foo` is some sort of hardware register - "logically impossible to be different" is just as good as "defined", no?

Comment: forgot we're talking about C, not c++ - scratch the overloaded `++` bit.  It would have to be a hardware register in order to make a difference.

Comment: No, scratch all that, you're definitely wrong.  ISO/IEC 9899:201x N570, page 85 (section 6.5.2.4 - Postfix increment and decrement operators), semantics item labeled 2: "The value computation of the result is sequenced before the side effect of updating the stored value of the operand."  Please fix.

Comment: @sqykly: Checking that reference... (Note: That's the opposite from the sequencing relationship you said earlier.)

Comment: "I'm saying that the value of the expression foo++ is defined to be the same as the value of foo (had it never been incremented at all)."  is pretty clear on what I meant and is neither confirmed nor refuted by that particular quote.  The first sentence of the same paragraph in the same standard, though, does support my statement.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46649/discussion-between-user2357112-and-sqykly)

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code and actually got "ffsoboep".

If you see that in other compilers you get "fernando", I believe that the following point is not defined in the standard:

```
*nombre=(*nombre)++;
```

This is post increment. The value of (x++) is the value of x before the increment (i.e., x == x++ is true).
The question is when does the increment is done.

If the increment is done immediately or after the evaluation of the right side of the = expression, then you first increment the value, and then re-assign the value of the expression (*nombre)++ (which is the value before the increment) to the already incremented *nombre.

If the increment is done, after all the expression is evaluated, then you first assign the (same) value to *nombre, and only then increment.

I think this is not defined in the standard, and therefore - you might see different behaviours. I encountered similar case in the past.